# Next.js: How to do client-side data fetching with grapql and headless CMS (graphCMS)

Tags: next.js, graphql, next.js13, graphcms

I'm currently facing an issue with fetching data in a client-side component using **Next.js app dir**, and I'm hoping to get some assistance with resolving it.

I have a specific requirement where I need to fetch data with graphql from graphCMS within a client-side component in Next.js. However, I'm unsure of the best approach to accomplish this. I have attempted a few different methods, but none of them seem to be working as expected.

#### Here's a simplified version of my component code:

This graphql request is located in a different file (**index.js**)

```
export async function getAllPosts() {
  const query = gql`
    query Posts {
      articles {
        id
        title
        excerpt
      }
    }
  `;
  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);
  return result.articles;
};
```

From my Home component, I am trying to get the data from `getAllPosta()` as follow. But in the console it ends in an boring infinite loop.

```
'use client'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default Home(){
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPosts().then((result) => {
      setData(result);
    });
  })

  return (
    data.map(post => {
      <div key={post.id}>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.excerpt}</p>
      </div>
    })
  )
}
```

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this simplified version of your code is close to the real implementation I would say that your problem is with `useEffect`. You don't have a dependency array so `useEffect` runs on every render, since it updates your component state with `setData(result)`, it will trigger a render causing `useEffect(...)` to run again and hence an infinite loop. If you only need to fetch the data once you just need to add `[]` to the dependencies. Your code should be something like this:

```
'use client'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home(){
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPosts().then((result) => {
      setData(result);
    });
  }, []) // <-- note the '[]' here
 
  return (
    data.map(post => {
      <div key={post.id}>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.excerpt}</p>
      </div>
    })
  )
}
```